# Is it possible to have SASL_PLAINTEXT communication between kafka and zookeeper and ScramLoginModule based login between kafka and kafka producer app?

Tags: apache-kafka, sasl

I am playing with Kafka locally in docker. I would like to set up the communication between the zookeeper and Kafka in a `SASL_PLAINTEXT` mode. But I want to set up the communication between Kafka and the Kafka producer using `org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule` this protocol.

So, in the Kafka producer client config, I can say

```
String saslJaasConfigValue =
        String.format(
            "org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username=%s password=%s", 
            username, pass);

put(SaslConfigs.SASL_JAAS_CONFIG, saslJaasConfigValue)
```

I think I've read somewhere that Kafka will store encrypted passwords in Zookeeper. Does that mean what I'm looking for is not possible?

If it's possible how do I do it?

Comment: SASL SCRAM is possible for clients while also having plaintext connection to Zookeeper... But the Zookeeper connection isn't done via the shown Java code, so I don't understand your question. Can you link to Kafka documentation where it says data in Zookeeper is encrypted?

Comment: I'll try to find the doc where it says, "data in Zookeeper is encrypted". But it's not from the official doc. That's why I was curious. Btw, can you point me to any doc where I can find how to do SASL SCRAM for client and broker and plaintext connection for Zookeeper and broker? I'm using `docker-compose` for the set btw

Comment: Here's where it says, user creds are stored in zookeeper. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-84%3A+Support+SASL+SCRAM+mechanisms $Credential configuration in Zookeeper _My understanding can be wrong here_

Comment: I've found the Confluent documentation on security is the most thorough, but the `server.properties` and `KAFKA_OPTS`environment variable in the broker is where you'd do any Zookeeper/JAAS configuration. But if you want plaintext there, then you don't need anything, just `zookeeper.connect`. Then SASL_SCRAM settings for clients would be defined as the `listeners` in the properties file